# .NET Multi tier Design LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, architecture, lazy-loading, multi-tier

I am quite new to the architecture and I am desiging an application for my next .NET project. My proposed architecture design is as follows:

It is traditional three tier application which contains:
DataLayer (LINQ + Partial Classes)
BusinessLogicLayer (Entities + Validation Logic)
(Optional) Service Layer (WCF)
UI (Web site and Windows App)

Data Layer:
The data layer will contains my DataContext classes (i.e. LINQ) and partial classes. These partial classes will have basic calculation logic (for e.g. Calc. VAT) and other database level validation logic.

Business Layer:
This will have entiries similar to Data Layer but also will contain validation logic at UI level. For e.g. if user try to enter username which does not exists in the database it needs to tell user that user does not exists. (this is the place where I am struggling). The object will be Lazy Loaded whenever the properties will be called and not when the Object is created.

UI:
This will be a traditional UI layer where Business entities will be invoked.

The reason why I am saperating the business layer from the DataLayer even when using LINQ is becouse if I wish to add more middle tier entities for e.g. WCF service then I want it to talk to Business Layer rather then Data. I belive decoupling helps when the application grows.(I think)

I would appriciate if someone can comment on above lines. My real problem is writing the business classes (obeviously). For e.g. In Lazy loading when I try to Load the Object and it there is no data in the database then I want my UI to show the user that the user does not exists (if I am searching for username). What are your recommondations with regards to this. Any input to this is much appriciated.

Many thanks,
Preyash

Answer (score 2):

One piece of advice here is to follow the KISS/YAGNI paradigms.  Don't necessarily dive in with a complex architecture just because you think you'll need it later when your application grows.

Maybe start with looking at exactly what your application needs to do, and think of the simplest way in which this can be achieved.  You will save your self loads of time and get a prototype up and running very quickly which will almost certainly teach you a lot about the problem that you can then factor in to the next version or enhancement.

With regards you question on the user interface, this is a good example of where keeping the architecture simple keeps everything else simple.  A simple method to load a user that returns null if the user doesn't exist can easily be interpreted by your UI.  But once you get into complex business objects you need to think through a lot more implications.  Your UI becomes tightly coupled to the complex business objects rather than a simple data access CRUD interface, so you might say your application has become more coupled rather than less.

My approach when creating applications for clients is generally to have as thin a server layer as possible.  Keeping the business logic with the data (i.e. in the database) and the UI logic in the UI (i.e. in the client), all the server does is pass very simple data objects between client/server using web services.

An alternative, if you're not a fan of logic in the database, would be to put the logic in services.

In both cases I think there is merit over putting the logic into new business entities, because if you do this you are passing your logic around the application and so increasing coupling, rather than passing the data and keeping the logic private.

Comment: @James:  To be helpful to the original question, how would you in a KISS/YAGNI environment propose to move from a basic design that had LINQ data access potentially all the way up in the UI or at the very least in the B/L into a tiered approach, etc?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying multi-tier application design is necessarily bad.  It's just a complicated approach that tends to work for large teams and large applications.  A small team/small app often benefits from just keeping everything as simple as possible.

Comment: Thats a good point. I have already invested many hours in the design and the very top level goal is for me to learn these types of arch. My previous projects were simple but the problem that found that whenever there is a requirement for a big change it usually ends up redo the design.
I understand its a common mistake to try to come up with something which is suitable for all senarios. But that is not what I am trying to achieve. The idea is to have a architecure in place which can accomodate most of my design needs.

Comment: I can fully understand your pain here!  I've updated the answer slightly to suggest thinking about putting the logic in the DB or adopt a service based approach.  But if a multi-tier/business objects approach is your preference then of course try that.  Any design can be made flexible if you plan it our carefully enough,  but in my experience the key factor that leads to flexibility is simplicity, not complexity.

Comment: i.c.Prob. have my business logic in service layer and let my service layer talk to the UI. That way you have only necessary entities passed between client and server. Does this mean my UI only have exposure to the Service Layer(e.g. WCF) and I have to write all my BLL in WCF?

Comment: Yes I keep all communication between UI and the server via a service layer - which in my case generally just feeds straight into a DB stored procedure.  You do need to duplicate logic in the UI and services (e.g. you need to do validation in both),  but this is common in client/server apps.  Personally I use validation attributes on my data that drive most of the client and service side validation automatically via reflection, but that's kind of getting off the point.